# Another probability event

Tags: probability

Good day, 
i would need a help.

How to compute a probability that three people let their hats in changingroom and lost their tickets. Then the girl gives them hats back in random way. What´s the probability that at least one of them got his hat?

I am really sorry to bother, but i kind of can not fuugure this thins as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 6 ways to rearnge $W_1=1,2,3, W_2=1,3,2, W_3=2,1,3 W_4=2,3,1, W_5=3,1,2$ and $W_6=3,2,1$. Supose people are $A,B,C$. In $W_1$ everyone gets his hats, in $W_2$ $A$, in $W_3$ $C$, in $W_4$ and $W_5$ no one and in $W_6$ $B$. So $P=\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 2):

You can list all the different ways the hats can be given back (say the people are called Alice, Bob and Charlie, and Alice originally had an [Akubra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akubra), Bob had a [Beret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beret), and Charlie had a [Chullo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chullo), and just start writing down the different ways the hats can be returned). There aren't that many, and they're all equally likely. Then you can count in how many of these ways at least one person got his hat back. Divide one of these numbers by the other, and you have your probability.